# How to fix a double move issue?

Tags: python, pong

TKINTER IN PYTHON

Ok, so I'm trying to make a 2 player pong game, and so far, I've encountered 3 issues. This is the 3rd that I honestly cannot get my head around (if you want to see where the issue arises, find the **#Ball movement logic**)

```
#Setting up the window

from tkinter import *

HEIGHT=500
WIDTH=800
window=Tk()

window.title('PONG!')
c=Canvas(window,width=WIDTH,height=HEIGHT,bg='black')
c.pack()

MID_X=WIDTH/2
MID_Y=HEIGHT/2
def pongstick():
    return c.create_polygon(0,0, 10,0, 10,70, 0,70, fill='white')
def ball():
    return c.create_oval(MID_X-10,MID_Y-10, MID_X+10,MID_Y+10, fill='white')

pong1=pongstick()
pong2=pongstick()
ballplay=ball()
MID_Y=MID_Y-35
c.move(pong1, 40, MID_Y)
c.move(pong2, WIDTH-40, MID_Y)

#Scores
player1p=0
player2p=0

#Movement of the paddles
stickspeed=10
def move_stick(event):
    if event.keysym == 'w':
        c.move(pong1, 0, -stickspeed)
    elif event.keysym == 's':
        c.move(pong1, 0, stickspeed)
    if event.keysym == 'Up':
        c.move(pong2, 0, -stickspeed)
    elif event.keysym == 'Down':
        c.move(pong2, 0, stickspeed)

#Ball movement logic
ballspeed=10
ballY=ballspeed
ballX=ballspeed
ballXadd=WIDTH/2
ballYadd=HEIGHT/2
def move_ball():
    c.move(ballplay, ballX, ballY)
    ballXadd=ballXadd+ballX
    ballYadd=ballYadd+ballY
    if ballXadd > WIDTH:
        player2p=player2p+1
        c.move(ball,MID_X-10,MID_Y-10)
        ballXadd=0
        ballYadd=0

    elif ballXadd < WIDTH:
        player1p=player1p+1
        c.move(ball,MID_X-10,MID_Y-10)
        ballXadd=0
        ballYadd=0

    elif ballYadd > HEIGHT:
        if ballX == ballspeed:
            ballY = -ballspeed
        elif ballX == -ballspeed:
            ballY = ballspeed

    elif ballYadd < HEIGHT:
        if ballX == ballspeed:
            ballY = ballspeed
        elif ballX == -ballspeed:
            ballY = -ballspeed

#GAME!
c.bind_all('<Key>',move_stick)
move_ball()
```

Issue is, I get the following error message whenever I run this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jackstrange/Documents/Untitled.py", line 79, in <module>
    move_ball()
  File "/Users/jackstrange/Documents/Untitled.py", line 50, in move_ball
    c.move(ballplay, ballX, ballY)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'ballY' referenced before assignment
```

There's probably something I'm missing which is seriously basic as all hell, like using a return command or something, but what confuses me is why ballX works but ballY doesn't. Some help would be nice :D

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that **c.move** will *change* the values of **ballX** and **ballY**.  If you want to change a global variable, you have to declare it **global** within the function.  You didn't do that; therefore, the **ballX/Y** variables in your function are local variables.

Given that, the error is easier to understand: you didn't define the *local* variables **ballX/Y**.

This is just one of many dangers of depending on global variables.

TO fix the problem, I suspect that all you need to do is to add one line at teh top of your function:

```
global ballX, ballY
```

Comment: Can you give me some advice in fixing it? Do I literally just set it in the function? Cuz that's irritating

Comment: Just found out that that was correct. Now I've come across another issue: how do I loop one part of the function without looping the other WHILE still keeping everything else moveable? Basically, how do I make the ball move, with hit detection, while allowing the paddles to move?

Comment: (1) That's a separate problem; please post a new question, per StackOverflow guidelines.  (2) As given, that question is far too broad to qualify on StackOverflow; it's essentially asking us to design a large portion of your game.

Answer (score 0):

change your `def move_ball()` declaration to `def move_ball(ballX, ballY)` and call it using `move_ball(ballX, ballY)`